# Show Taps in TapBarViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a `TapBarViewController` with three Taps in my project.

Now I am trying to put a normal `FirstViewController` in front of the `TapBar ViewController` when the application launches.

The `FirstViewController` should have three buttons for one of the individual Taps of the `TapBarViewController`.

How can I show the individual Taps of the `TapBarViewController` by pressing one of the three buttons?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQNHb.png)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide some screenshots.

Comment: I added a picture for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the exact answer you are looking for.

**Steps:**

1. Add a `UIViewcontroller` and embed with `UINavigationViewController` (Editor -> EmbedIn -> NavigationController).
2. Add Three button + 1 Button (Navigate to TabViewController).
3. Drag and drop `UITabBarController` to the storyboard it comes with one default ViewController and place a UILabel named as 'ButtonOneClicked'.
4. Create Two more ViewControllers and named as 'ButtonTwoClicked' and 'ButtonThreeClicked'.
5. Connect 'ButtonOne' with `FirstViewController` and set segue as **`Show`** and repeat the same for rest two.
6. Click on each segue and provide an unique Identifier name.
7. Then connect the `UITabBarController` with each UIViewController and choose **`viewcontrollers`**
8. Create a ButtonAction to the `Tab` Button.
9. Copy paste the below code in that action.

   ```
   @IBAction func tabClicked(_ sender: Any) {
       let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
       appDelegate.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
       let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
       let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Tab") as! UITabBarController
       appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
       appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()}
   ```

[image: Please find the storyboard structure below]

Hope this helps you!!

Comment: This is actually not how I want it to be. I just want a initial FirstViewController which has these three buttons, which call one of the three TapBarViewControllers and I don't want to show the FirstViewController appear again except when the App is restarted.

Comment: Use the code from 'tabClicked' button action and send some unique tag to the UITabbarController to open their respective ViewController.

Comment: self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1; // 1 or 2 or 3. Call this line in TabBarViewController's ViewWillAppear().